# Trim string contents to get only the ID value

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am trying to figure out how to trim a string so I get just the ID int value. I have a text box that can accept ID values so long as they are formatted like [@ID=#] 9. It can also accept BP [which stands for, "base price"] and valid numbers and math operators). What I need to do is get the number in that string and test to see if it is a valid ID. I have created a function that trims out the unnecessary characters and gets just the ID:

```
protected int CheckValidID(string idString)
{
    bool IsValid = false;
    int ValidID = 0;
    String trimmedId = idString.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '[', '@', 'I', 'D', '=', ']' });

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT OptionChoiceId FROM ac_OptionChoices WHERE OptionChoiceId = @OptionChoiceID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OptionChoiceID", trimmedId);
        cn.Open();

        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
                if (reader["OptionChoiceId"].ToString() != "")
                {
                    IsValid = true;
                    ValidID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["OptionChoiceId"]);
                }

        }
        cn.Close();
    }
    return ValidID;
}
```

If the ID passed in is valid, then I need to replace that ID with a number (any number).

```
 if (PriceFormula.Text != "")
    {
        string pFormula = PriceFormula.Text;
        if (pFormula.Contains("@ID"))
        {
            CheckValidID(pFormula);
            if (CheckValidID(pFormula) != 0)
                pFormula = pFormula.Replace(PriceFormula.Text, "2");
        }
        pFormula = pFormula.Replace("BP", "2");
        pFormula = pFormula.ToLower();      
        try
        {
            double n = 0;
            bool priceVal = (!Double.TryParse(ItemLookUp.evalExpression(pFormula).ToString(), out n));
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            isValid = false;
            ErrorNote.Text += "This new option choice has an invalid Price Formula. <br />";
        }

    }
```

The problem I have is if a user types in something like [@ID=#]*9, which is meant to be valid but doesn't work for what I have set up. Also, it doesn't work even if the user enters a valid ID. How can I set things up so that I can retrieve just the ID part of [@ID=#] regardless of whether it is typed into the text field on its own or with numbers and math operators?

In the end, I need to test if what the user put in actually returns a valid result (in this case, a valid double). Either the ID or the BP text is replaced with a number (here I use 2) and that allows the formula to be tested. But it's the ID part that's got me stuck.

Examples of VALID entries for the text field:

1. [@ID=532134]
2. [@ID=828718]*2
3. [@ID=347479]*3+2
4. BP*2
5. BP+6
6. BP*5+3

Examples of INVALID entries:

1. [ID=38288]
2. @ID=383793
3. [@ID=39371]+
4. BP+
5. BP*2'
6. BP+9*
7. BC*6

Comment: Please put backticks (the key `\``, which is left of the 1 key on US keyboards) around what your input formats are. It's hard to figure it out.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do here. Can you add some example strings that might be entered and which part you are actually trying to extract. With some cases that are acceptable and some that should fail.

Comment: Would it not be easier to just make the text box only accept numbers, and then put `[@ID=` and `]` text blocks next to it?

Comment: I added examples of valid and invalid entries. 
@Pyritie That sounds like a good idea but users are allowed to enter in mathematical operators. Plus, setting the text field up with [@ID= and ] book-ending it is not what was requested.

Comment: This sounds like you should define a grammar and user a lexer/parser. The second you said "mathematical operators" its probably way beyond doing stuff with a regex only.

Comment: What you need to do is build a separate function that scans a passed in string for `[@ID=`. If found, it then checks that the string also contains `]` and that the input string's length is greater than the combined length of `[@ID=` and `]`. If all those conditions are met, then it grabs the substring of the input string starting at `"[@ID=".Length` + 1, and goes for theInputString.Length - `"]".Length`. It then takes that substring, checks that it is numeric, and uses a TryParse to number. Finally, it returns that number value, if any.

Comment: @StarPilot This sounds like a good idea...I will give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format is the given one, then I don't see that much of an issue:

```
 var startIndex= inputString.IndexOf("[@ID=");
 var endIndex = inputString.LastIndexOf("]");

 if (startIndex < 0 || endIndex < startIndex)
     throw new ArgumentException("Format is not valid.");

 startIndex += "[@ID=".Length;
 var potentialIdString = inputString.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
 int id;

 if (int.TryParse(potentialIdString, out id))
      return id;
 else
     throw new ArgumentException("ID is not valid.");
```

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expressions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public int CheckValidID(string idString)
{

    Regex rg = new Regex(@"\d*",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    string val = rg.Match(idString).Value;

    int ValidID = Convert.ToInt32(val);

    return ValidID;

}
```